# Shapefiles do not appear or adversely affects GIS map

Tags: gis, arcgis, shapefile, qgis

I've been working with GIS software for several years and have never encountered this issue before. Several troubleshooting sessions through web searches haven't yielded much. For my workflow, I have attempted by two options to apply tabular data to create features on ArcGIS and on QGIS. My first attempt wrote a spreadsheet to a shapefile by the "simple features" software package of the R Studio environment. The result created the expected .dbf, .shp, .prj and .shx file. The uploaded shapefile appeared but rendered accompanying shapefiles as well as the basemap layers. This occurred in ArcGISPRO and QGIS software. For my second attempt, I processed tabular data through the "Open Data Source Manager" window, selecting the NAD83/New York Long Island(ftUS)/EPSG: 2263 CRS. The GPS coordinates are based on degrees of latitude and longitude. Points displayed correctly in my QGIS project data view but again, the other layers and the basemap of my project were compromised. I tried a separate avenue within this second attempt by uploading this tabular data, but instead selecting the default CRS (WGS 84, EPSG: 4326). No points were displayed. How do I write this tabular data effectively without compromising the entire project? Any kind of insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your points are in lat/lon then you need to select epsg:4326 WGS84 as their projection.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to QGIS, but in ArcGIS Pro you should use the [XY Table to Point Tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/xy-table-to-point.htm).  This will create a Shapefile for you (be sure when defining the **Output Feature Class** input you put .shp on the end of the name; Pro doesn't always clue in to that being the desired output if you don't).  Yes, you will have to convert your spreadsheet to a .csv or .txt file, but I recommend doing that anyways.  I've found ESRI's ability to read spreadsheets is a bit hit and miss, resulting in some weird results in the data after conversion.

Also, I don't understand why you tried using two different projections.  The data should be in a given projection, telling a tool that you are using a different one is just going to create data in the wrong location.  If you want to move from one projection to another, create the shapefile in the source data's projection and then use [the Project tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/project.htm) to move it to the other.  Then you can also be sure that the desired transformation is applied to the data.